# How to push array data into a data attribute

Tags: javascript

I have a div as shown below

```
var mydiv = '<div  id="100" data-stuff="[]"></div>' ;
```

Now i have a JSON array

```
var vendoritemsdata = [{"name":"892_KK_0_KK_0tab1_checkbox","cost":10,"additionname":"t10","addtionid":69},{"name":"892_KK_1_KK_0tab1_checkbox","cost":11,"additionname":"t11","addtionid":70}];
```

I am trying to push each element of array to above data attribute stuff

http://jsfiddle.net/cod7ceho/493/

Comment: `mydiv` is a string. It doesn't have arrays and there's nothing to push. Are you turning it into an actual HTML element at any point?

Comment: Check the answer, that should be the one you need

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply set the `data-stuff` attribute of the element using JQuery. Before that you need to convert the array of JSON objects to string so use `JSON.stringify()`.

```js
var vendoritemsdata = [{"name":"892_KK_0_KK_0tab1_checkbox","cost":10,"additionname":"t10","addtionid":69},{"name":"892_KK_1_KK_0tab1_checkbox","cost":11,"additionname":"t11","addtionid":70}];

$('#100').attr('data-stuff', JSON.stringify(vendoritemsdata));

//retrieving
var dataStuff = $('#100').attr('data-stuff');
dataStuff = JSON.parse(dataStuff);
console.log('length is '+dataStuff.length);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div  id="100" data-stuff="[]">This is a div</div>
```

Inspect the element `This is a div` and check that the `data-stuff` attribute contains the array values.

To retrieve the value, you need to parse the string to get the array of JSON.

Comment: thanks but when extracted the length of the array is not 2 .

Comment: What do you mean please elaborate it. We can be close to the solution you expect

Comment: when i extract the data stuff and read it ($("#100").attr('data-stuff').length;) the length is not 2  (i mean its treated as a string not an array)

Comment: Ok, i have edited my answer. Check the code from //retrieving comment.

Comment: Please let me know if you are still looking for something else or any changes required

Comment: thanks a lot for your time , its working .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153681/discussion-between-aka-and-pawan).